# How to get some values from xml

Tags: xml, database, servlets

As I'm uploading xml document through html and passing it to servlet. In servlet I've to extract some fields of xml and send it to database(I've created one table in database(mysql)) along with the file(xml).

Any suggestions??

### My index.html

```
<!doctype html public "-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 transitional//en">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Con`tent-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
     <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Mozilla/4.61 [en] (WinNT; I) [Netscape]">
      <title> </title>
  </head>
  <body>    
      <form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          File:
             <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br/>    
             <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="upload" />
       </form>
  </body>
```

### My InsertXMLServlet.java(Servlet)

```
    package com;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
    import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class InsertXMLServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "InsertXMLServlet", urlPatterns = { "/upload" })
public class InsertXMLServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public InsertXMLServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        int rows = 0;

        // File xmlFile = new File("D:Name.xml");

        final Part filePart = request.getPart("file");

        OutputStream out = null;
        InputStream filecontent = null;
        final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        try {

            filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

            int read = 0;
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + path);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {

            writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (filecontent != null) {
                filecontent.close();
            }
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://@inblrl0746/test";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "password";
        String INSERT_SQL = "INSERT INTO ATTACHMENT(FILENAME,CONTENT) values(?, ?)";

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
            ps.setString(1, xmlFile.getName());
            ps.setBinaryStream(2, new FileInputStream(xmlFile));
            rows = ps.executeUpdate();
            return rows;

        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // ps.close();
            // con.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();// CLOSE ps and con;
        } finally {
            ps.close();
            con.close();

        }
        return rows;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to get some fields from xml in the servlet??

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me in finding the solution??